# How to execute R language script from Android app?

Tags: android, c++, r, android-ndk

I'm writing an application for Android devices and try to find a capability to execute R script from Kotlin/Java/C++(NDK). Is there a way to do so or maybe somewhere there are tools that can help to convert R language into the language mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rcaller](https://github.com/jbytecode/rcaller) with Java. I've heard about [Renjin](https://www.renjin.org/) but i've had no experience with that one, I'm pretty sure there are other external libraries but I've used the first one.

> **RCaller** is a production ready library for calling R functions from
> within Java.

> **Renjin** is a essentially a Java library that allows you to evaluate
> scripts written in the R language.

EDIT:

You can add them with:

```
implementation group: 'com.github.jbytecode', name: 'RCaller', version: '2.8'

implementation "org.renjin:renjin-script-engine:XXX";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the direction. However, these libraries are intended for desktop apps and unfortunately, there is no possibility to deploy them on a mobile device with Android OS.

Comment: The RCaller requires R installed in the runtime environment. Sounds like the R package has to be included in Android application but it is impossible :-(